# NetworkX: Find second level of nodes

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph, networkx

I have a directed User Graph `G`. I am trying to make a function where I can return `User` nodes at `n` level.

```
def findNodes(node, level):
 return #nodes at this level
```

Using `nx.bfs_successors(G,node)` returns all of the successors as a list which can take up memory for large number of nodes.

Comment: By level, do you mean distance?

Comment: a->b->c->d, c is second level node of a

Answer (score 0):

You know about `nx.ego_graph`, right?

```
 def find_nodes(graph, node, distance):

     # get all nodes within distance around the query node
     nodes = set(nx.ego_graph(graph, node, radius=distance))

     # remove nodes that are not **at** the specified distance but closer
     if distance > 1:
         nodes -= set(nx.ego_graph(graph, node, radius=distance-1))

     return list(nodes)
```